# I am using Sinch for instant messages it is working fine till OS 7.0 but never working on 8.0 or above

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, sinch, android-9.0-pie

in MessageClientListener interface onMessageSent never called in Oreo and Nougat

```
void onMessageSent(MessageClient var1, Message var2, String var3);
```

Comment: What's the `targetSdkVersion` of your app in `build.gradle`?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: The documentation mentions to use `26`, so maybe there's an issue with background execution limits. http://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/user-guide/index.html

Comment: your answer worked for me.

Christopher you are great, you are genius I must say.